# Slow Authentication on Arch Linux using NSLCD and Windows AD

Tags: linux, active-directory, authentication, ldap, windows-authentication

I recently built a Arch Linux server that authenticates using NSLCD connecting to Windows AD. The authentication works, but there is a long delay (approx 10 seconds) between entering a password and getting to a prompt.

On the AD users are being stored in 3 different OUs, "Faculty and Staff", "Students", and "Computer Science".

Here is the mappings section of my nslcd.conf

```
pagesize 1000
referrals off
idle_timelimit 800
filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*)(unixHomeDirectory=*))
map    passwd uid              sAMAccountName
map    passwd homeDirectory    unixHomeDirectory
map    passwd gecos            displayName
filter shadow (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*)(unixHomeDirectory=*))
map    shadow uid              sAMAccountName
map    shadow shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
filter group  (objectClass=group)
```

Customize certain database lookups.

```
#base   group  ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
base   group  ou=Computer Science,dc=muad,dc=local
#base   passwd ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
base   passwd ou=Faculty and Staff,dc=muad,dc=local
base   passwd ou=Computer Science,dc=muad,dc=local
base   passwd ou=Students,dc=muad,dc=local
#base   shadow ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
#scope  group  onelevel
#scope  hosts  sub
```

I have also started the nscd service to see if that helps cache info from the AD to speed up the login process.

Here is what my /etc/pam.d/system-auth config file:

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth      sufficient pam_ldap.so
auth      required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok
auth      optional  pam_permit.so
auth      required  pam_env.so

account   sufficient pam_ldap.so
account   required  pam_unix.so
account   optional  pam_permit.so
account   required  pam_time.so

password  sufficient pam_ldap.so
password  required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok sha512 shadow
password  optional  pam_permit.so

session   required  pam_limits.so
session   required  pam_unix.so

session   required  pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0077

session   optional  pam_ldap.so
session   optional  pam_permit.so
```

Previously we were using NIS and that was speedy with authentication. But we would like to get that 10 second delay to be next to nothing. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If you would like to see any further files, please ask.

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: Have you tried monitoring network traffic to check _what_ takes so much time?

Comment: We are fairly confident that it is not a network issue. We have close to 35,000 objects in our AD. So searching through all that probably isn't helping. Then after a few logins, it seems like it is using NSCD to cache the login and it speeds up.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that it could reveal many more things than just 'network issues'. For example, some specific query taking 10 seconds to reply.